# Windows 10 won't see plugged hdd in whose windows 10 is installed

Tags: windows, windows-10

m an I.T tech at a small repair shop.

This happens often :

I have a windows 10 PC and a external HDD in whose Windows 10 is installed inside and has some important data in this location : C:\Users.

I plug in the HDD via SATA connection or USB to transfer the data but can't access it on the Windows 10 PC.

What happens is that i cant see other windows 10 installations data in windows 10 PC.

I want to know if there is some trick to make this work

Comment: I just answered this question yesterday, take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/1161917/taking-ownership-of-hard-drive-does-not-reveal-files/1161930#1161930

Comment: Your linked answer doesn't explain the reason their Windows installation doesn't see the drive.  The linked question is an answer to an entirely different situation.  In the linked question, the volume mounts, which tells me something else is going in this case

Comment: @Alexei can you use a different SATA to USB device.  The fact it's not mounting the volume with a drive tells me the one you have isn't functioning